# How to extract coordinates(lat, lan) from a URL in Python?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, coordinates

I'm a bit lost on how to extract coordinates (Lat, Long) from a URL in Python.

Always I'll recive a url like this:

```
https://www.testweb.com/cordi?ll=41.403781,2.1896&z=17&pll=41.403781,2.1896
```

Where I need to extract the second set of this URL (in this case: 41.403781,2.1896) Just to say, that not always the first and second set of coords will be the same.

I know, that can be done with some regex, but I'm not good enough on it.

Comment: Surely there's a decent URL parser for Python out there?

Comment: Does it always comes last in the URL ? Because if that is the case then `[\d.,]+$` will do the work. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rB7mF9/2)

Comment: Thanks Biffen, I'll take a look if exist something . Yes @noob this is allways the pattern.

Comment: Updated the demo to extract only coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it with a regular expression:

```
import re
m = re.search(r'pll=(\d+\.\d+),(\d+\.\d+)', 'https://www.testweb.com/cordi?ll=41.403781,2.1896&z=17&pll=41.403781,2.1896')
print m.groups()
```

Result: `('41.403781', '2.1896')`

You might want look at the module `urlparse` for a more robust solution.

Answer (score 1):

urlparse has a functions "urlparse" and "parse_qs" for accessing this data reliably, as shown below

```
$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 23 2015, 15:22:56) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> u="""https://www.testweb.com/cordi?ll=41.403781,2.1896&z=17&pll=41.403781,2.1896"""
>>> import urlparse
>>> x=urlparse.urlparse(u)
>>> x
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='www.testweb.com', path='/cordi', params='', query='ll=41.403781,2.1896&z=17&pll=41.403781,2.1896', fragment='')
>>> x.query
'll=41.403781,2.1896&z=17&pll=41.403781,2.1896'
>>> urlparse.parse_qs(x.query)
{'ll': ['41.403781,2.1896'], 'z': ['17'], 'pll': ['41.403781,2.1896']}
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look